# Xcode gives Linker command failed with exit code 1 when using fstream

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, linker, fstream

I can compile code on Xcode fine, until i try to use fstream, then I keep getting this error.

I was wondering maybe it is the extension of .txt on Mac? I use the exact same code on my Windows laptop with Dev C++ and it works fine...

Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i, x, A[17], B[17], n;
    ifstream df ("input.txt");
    df>>n;
    df>>x;
    for (i=0; i<n; i=i+1)
    {
        df>>A[i];
        cout<<A[i];
    }
    df.close ();
    for (i=0; i<n; i=i+1)
    {
        B[i]=A[i]+x;
        cout<<B[i];
    }
    ofstream rf ("results.txt");
    for (i=0; i<n; i=i+1)
    {
        rf<<B[i]<<" ";
    }
    rf.close ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the extension, the problem is that you are linking incorrectly. Probably you aren't linking with the C++ libraries. Unfortunately I don't know Xcode so I can't offer any more advice.

Comment: @john sorry just to clarify you mean that the fstream library isn't recognized?

Comment: I mean that you aren't telling Xcode to link with the library that contains `fstream`. It might help if you posted the full error message.

Comment: The full error message is "Linker command failed with exit code 1"